# Error with route in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

New rails user here.  I am trying to have a user enter an amount on a form located at /games, save the amount, then forward to /game, but am having trouble with my routes.

Navigating to /game results in the error **"No route matches [GET] "/game"**"

I've run this on console:

> rails generate controller game index

Here is my route file:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  get "game/index"
  resources :users
  resources :invoices
  resources :payments
  resources :rolls
  resources :bets
  resources :gamerounds
  resources :games

  root "games#index"
end
```

Here's the rest of the error message, listing available routes:

```
game_index_path  GET     /game/index(.:format)   game#index
welcome_index_path   GET     /welcome/index(.:format)    welcome#index
users_path   GET     /users(.:format)    users#index
POST     /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path    GET     /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path   GET     /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path    GET     /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT  /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
invoices_path    GET     /invoices(.:format)     invoices#index
POST     /invoices(.:format)     invoices#create
new_invoice_path     GET     /invoices/new(.:format)     invoices#new
edit_invoice_path    GET     /invoices/:id/edit(.:format)    invoices#edit
invoice_path     GET     /invoices/:id(.:format)     invoices#show
PATCH    /invoices/:id(.:format)     invoices#update
PUT  /invoices/:id(.:format)     invoices#update
DELETE   /invoices/:id(.:format)     invoices#destroy
payments_path    GET     /payments(.:format)     payments#index
POST     /payments(.:format)     payments#create
new_payment_path     GET     /payments/new(.:format)     payments#new
edit_payment_path    GET     /payments/:id/edit(.:format)    payments#edit
payment_path     GET     /payments/:id(.:format)     payments#show
PATCH    /payments/:id(.:format)     payments#update
PUT  /payments/:id(.:format)     payments#update
DELETE   /payments/:id(.:format)     payments#destroy
rolls_path   GET     /rolls(.:format)    rolls#index
POST     /rolls(.:format)    rolls#create
new_roll_path    GET     /rolls/new(.:format)    rolls#new
edit_roll_path   GET     /rolls/:id/edit(.:format)   rolls#edit
roll_path    GET     /rolls/:id(.:format)    rolls#show
PATCH    /rolls/:id(.:format)    rolls#update
PUT  /rolls/:id(.:format)    rolls#update
DELETE   /rolls/:id(.:format)    rolls#destroy
bets_path    GET     /bets(.:format)     bets#index
POST     /bets(.:format)     bets#create
new_bet_path     GET     /bets/new(.:format)     bets#new
edit_bet_path    GET     /bets/:id/edit(.:format)    bets#edit
bet_path     GET     /bets/:id(.:format)     bets#show
PATCH    /bets/:id(.:format)     bets#update
PUT  /bets/:id(.:format)     bets#update
DELETE   /bets/:id(.:format)     bets#destroy
gamerounds_path  GET     /gamerounds(.:format)   gamerounds#index
POST     /gamerounds(.:format)   gamerounds#create
new_gameround_path   GET     /gamerounds/new(.:format)   gamerounds#new
edit_gameround_path  GET     /gamerounds/:id/edit(.:format)  gamerounds#edit
gameround_path   GET     /gamerounds/:id(.:format)   gamerounds#show
PATCH    /gamerounds/:id(.:format)   gamerounds#update
PUT  /gamerounds/:id(.:format)   gamerounds#update
DELETE   /gamerounds/:id(.:format)   gamerounds#destroy
games_path   GET     /games(.:format)    games#index
POST     /games(.:format)    games#create
new_game_path    GET     /games/new(.:format)    games#new
edit_game_path   GET     /games/:id/edit(.:format)   games#edit
game_path    GET     /games/:id(.:format)    games#show
PATCH    /games/:id(.:format)    games#update
PUT  /games/:id(.:format)    games#update
DELETE   /games/:id(.:format)    games#destroy
root_path    GET     /   games#index
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using two differents name for the same resource `games` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly created a route called `game/index`, so if you go to `localhost:3000/game/index`, it'll work.

Adjust your route of `get "game/index"` to `get "game"` - that should solve this immediate issue.